# Why is the super constructor necessary in PyTorch custom modules?

Tags: python, inheritance, pytorch, super

Why does `super(LR, self).__init__()` need to be called in the code below? I get the error "AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.**init**() call" otherwise. That error is caused by `self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)`.

I don't understand what the connection is between calling `super(LR, self).__init__()` and being able to assign the nn.Linear object to self.linear. nn.Linear is a separate object which can be assigned to a variable outside of any class, so why does `super(LR, self).__init__()` need to be called to assign a Linear object to self.linear within the class?

```
class LR(nn.Module):
    
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        
        # Inherit from parent
        super(LR, self).__init__()
        self.test = 1
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)
        
    
    # Prediction function
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out
```

Answer (score 15):

When you write `self.linear = nn.Linear(...)` inside your custom class, you are actually calling the `__setattr__` function of your class. It just happens that  when you extend `nn.Module`, there are a bunch of things that your class is inheriting, and one of them is the [`__setattr__`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c0e38398459ef107b7afa7d23024b28c9c151e97/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L778-L823). As you can see in the implementation (I post only the relevant part below), if `nn.Linear` is an instance of `nn.Module`, your class must have an attribute called `_modules`, otherwise it will throw the `AttributeError` you got:

```py
def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Union[Tensor, 'Module']) -> None:
    # [...]
    modules = self.__dict__.get('_modules')
    if isinstance(value, Module):
        if modules is None:
            raise AttributeError("cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call")
        remove_from(self.__dict__, self._parameters, self._buffers, self._non_persistent_buffers_set)
        modules[name] = value
```

If you take a look at the `nn.Module`'s [`__init__`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/266657182a4040937f6f27011d7ddf77716db83d/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L206-L221), you'll see that `self._modules` is initialized there:

```py
def __init__(self):
    """
    Initializes internal Module state, shared by both nn.Module and ScriptModule.
    """
    torch._C._log_api_usage_once("python.nn_module")

    self.training = True
    self._parameters = OrderedDict()
    self._buffers = OrderedDict()
    self._non_persistent_buffers_set = set()
    self._backward_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._forward_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._forward_pre_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._state_dict_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._load_state_dict_pre_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._modules = OrderedDict()                         # <---- here
```

The same is true for buffers and parameters.

Comment: Yep. I dug into the source and figured it out. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @chmod_777 Open-source is the best :) If you think this answers your question and might be helpful for others, consider upvoting it or marking as answer.

Answer (score 5):

you need the super() call so that the mn.Module class itself is initialised. IN Python superclass constructors/initialisers aren't called automatically - they have to be called explicitly, and that is what super() does - it works out what superclass to call.

I assume you are using Python 3 - in which case you don't need the arguments in the super() call - this is sufficient :

```
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: Interesting, does that mean that pytorch documentation still points to old way of calling super then which is weird..?
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html